# Wifi gone after reinstall, Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, wireless

My wifi was working perfectly, but after a failed attempt to install an Nvme SSD (which involved numerous Ubuntu 20 and then 19 installations from USB to that new SSD) I had to fall back and reinstall Ubuntu 19.10 on my original drive.

After doing so there is no Wifi support in the network applet or in the system menu (top right on my desktop), but there is wired connection support in both. The wifi menu is also now not visible when booting from USB. My wired connection works properly.

Based on this question ([My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)) I've generated a network diagnostic dump and 
copied to pastebin at https://pastebin.com/44cwwb5V

output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list is as follows

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of dmesg | grep iwl is as follows:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.584148] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.602662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.602664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    4.603065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.721463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9460, REV=0x318
[    4.732443] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.732911] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.737671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    4.737678] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    4.737708] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    4.737718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCAAAFDB7 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    4.737727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x39FF0DCF | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.737737] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x82B7EC7C | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.737740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDFE4D94D | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    4.737751] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x45B05A33 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    4.737760] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB78CCEC4 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    4.737770] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x899F4F6A | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    4.737780] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2F3462E4 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    4.737791] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.737834] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.737909] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    4.737984] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    4.738215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[    4.738218] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    4.738222] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    4.984307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    4.995478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

Help appreciated

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Added. I note the 'Microcode SW error detected', so this is looking like a hardware issue?

Comment: Can you format text youself? This is a kernel bug. I suggest upgradeing kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic`. This should be fixed. And also `sudo apt install linux-firmware`

Comment: I don't think it is a hardware issue.

Comment: Interesting, I was running Linux 19.10 on the same hardware before and the wifi was fine, but after reinstalling the wifi was gone; same problem now when booting from a live USB.

Comment: Regarding linux-generic and linux-firmware it sounds like that would impact all of the device drivers etc? Just wondering about the risk - this is my primary work laptop

Comment: This shouldn't affect anything. Yhis is a normal update. Alternatively you cab run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. The first method upgrades only related packages.

Comment: I'm just coming back to this and tried all of the above with no success, still no wifi settings visible anywhere. The really odd thing to me is that wifi it worked fine with both Ubuntu 19.04 and then Ubuntu 10, both from a bootable USB stick and after installation, but now even a bootable USB 19.10 does not have wifi.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong entries in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`.

Replace the contents of this file with

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Comment: Thanks - but no change after replacing the content and rebooting, wifi options are still not visible in the applet or system menu.

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` to your question.

Comment: added to question; output is as follows 00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
 DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0000]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no